# Wordpress: Display success or failure for register_settings()

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress's register_setting() to save a certain setting. After hitting submit the page refreshed but I don't get any feedback like "Successfully saved setting". How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want output, write code to produce output:

```
register_setting(...whatever...)
echo "Successfully saved setting";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use

```
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
```

at top of submit class